# in a function inside a .c file from a C project, how to reuse a allocated memeory so that I dont do malloc-free frequently?

Tags: c, project

I have a function inside which I need to use a pointer to a structure, like

```
      void func(struct Info* info){
         struct Block *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Block));
         sub_func1(p, info);         // here will fill the content pointed by p
         sub_func2(p);               // here just use content in p
         free(p);
      }
```

this function is inside a `.c` file and the `.c` file is one file of a c project.
I want to reuse the allocated memory so that I don't need to frequently `malloc` and `free`. Namely, I just do the `malloc` for once. 
But I'm at a loss where to define and pointer and do the `malloc`, can anyone give some advice?

BTW, if I have some static variables and static functions in a `.c` file, do I need to declare them in the corresponding `.h` file, like `extern static var;` or `extern static void func();`?

thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `malloc()` at all?

Comment: This is called micro-optimization. In the vast majority of cases, you shouldn't worry about a few extra `malloc` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
void func(struct Info* info){
     struct Block p;
     sub_func1(&p, info);         // here will fill p
     sub_func2(&p);               // here just use content in p
}
```

The only reason to use `malloc()` is if `struct Block` is too big to fit on the stack.

Comment: is that resource costly? frequently initializing a struct variable

Comment: @misteryes: Not as costly as using `malloc()`.

Comment: @misteryes allocating a stack variable is nothing but incrementing the stack pointer (a register). the initialization has nothing to do with the allocation method.

Answer (score 0):

To your second quesion: `static` variables need not, and can not, be declared outside the .c file they are defined in. that's the whole point of them being static - that is, local to the compilation unit.

`extern static int x;` is an oxymoron.